Why is the size of two different class objects the same?
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class Trie{
    int a;
    Trie * child[26];
};

class Trie2{
    int a;
    char b;
    Trie * child[26];
};

int main()
{
    cout<<sizeof(Trie)<<endl;
    cout<<sizeof(Trie2)<<endl;
    return 0;
}

Both classes output as 216 bytes. I could understand for the first type Trie (4 (for integers) + 4 (for padding) + 26 x 8), but I can't understand for the second type Trie2.
I ran the code, and was expecting different results.

What size would you have expected for the second and why?

On a side note: Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?

also check What's the problem with "using namespace std;"?

What do you know about memory alignment and padding?

This question is similar to: Why isn't sizeof for a struct equal to the sum of sizeof of each member?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This is due to the alignment. The pointer array is aligned on pointer boundaries.  This is implementation dependent, but in your case probably 64 bits.  In your implementation, the size of an int seems to be smaller than the difference between two aligned addresses for pointers.  So the extra byte for char does not make any difference.
Try making a an int*  or a long (again, all this is implementation dependent),  and you'll probably see that the extra char will this time matter.  Also due to alignment matters, the difference will not necessarily be 1.
Online demo.
You can easily discover the size of a type, and also its alignment requirements used by your compiler:
cout<<sizeof(Trie*)<<","<<alignof(Trie*)<<endl; 
cout<<sizeof(int)<<","<<alignof(int)<<endl; 
cout<<sizeof(int*)<<","<<alignof(int*)<<endl; 
cout<<sizeof(char)<<","<< alignof(char)<<endl; 

alignof 8 means that the address of an object of the type must be a multiple of the alignment factor.

I assume you are talking about 64-bit machine, since you said "26 x 8". Here's how a typical 64-bit machine sees your structs:
struct Trie {
    [4 bytes] a;
    [4 bytes] padding;
    [26x8 bytes] child;
};

struct Trie2 {
    [4 bytes] a;
    [1 byte] b;
    [3 bytes] padding;
    [26x8 bytes] child;
};

Which follows from the fact that int takes 4 bytes, pointers are aligned to 8, and char takes 1 byte and is aligned to 1. So it fits in the padding of the previous struct.
Note that the result will be different on a 32-bit machine. Most certainly Trie2 will be bigger, because pointers will be aligned to 4 instead of 8. So there will be no padding in the first Trie, but the second one will still need it.

This is how padding in structures/classes works on a 64 bit PC:
#include <iostream>

struct Trie {
  int a;
  Trie* child[26];
};

struct Trie2 {
  int a;
  char b;
  Trie* child[26];
};

int main() {
  std::cout << "Trie::a location " << offsetof(Trie, a) << " to "
            << offsetof(Trie, a) + sizeof(Trie::a) << "\n";
  std::cout << "Trie::child location " << offsetof(Trie, child) << " to "
            << offsetof(Trie, child) + sizeof(Trie::child) << "\n";
  std::cout << "Trie2::a location " << offsetof(Trie2, a) << " to "
            << offsetof(Trie2, a) + sizeof(Trie2::a) << "\n";
  std::cout << "Trie2::b location " << offsetof(Trie2, b)  << " to "
            << offsetof(Trie2, b) + sizeof(Trie2::b) << "\n";
  std::cout << "Trie2::child location " << offsetof(Trie2, child)  << " to "
            << offsetof(Trie2, child) + sizeof(Trie2::child) << "\n";
}

Output
Trie::a location 0 to 4
Trie::child location 8 to 216
Trie2::a location 0 to 4
Trie2::b location 4 to 5
Trie2::child location 8 to 216

As you can see, there is 4 byte gaps between a and child. This is due to the array alignment usually for performance. Trie2 partially fills that gap with b. The sizeof(Trie2) is not changed. If you make b bigger, for example double b, it will not fit into the gap and Trie2 will be bigger.

Both Trie and Trie2 end up taking 216 bytes because of how memory alignment works. Even though Trie2 has an extra char variable, the compiler adds padding after it to make sure the array of pointers (child[26]) starts at an 8-byte boundary (which is required for pointers on a 64-bit system). This padding makes the total size of both classes the same, even though the structure of the two classes is slightly different.
